# Measurable spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, functions

I've got problem with this exercise:
Let $(X,\mathcal{A})$ , $(Y,\mathcal{D})$ be measurable spaces, and a mapping $T : X \rightarrow Y$ is $T(X) = Y_{0}$ . Show that $T : (X,\mathcal{A})\rightarrow (Y,\mathcal{D})$ if and only if $T : (X,A)\rightarrow (Y_{0},\mathcal{D}_{Y_{0}})$.

Comment: What is $Y_0$? Just the range of the function $T$?

Comment: Yes, i think... I translated it from my language so maybe it isn't clear. Word for word from my language: $T$ is a mapping such that $T(X)=Y_{0}$.

Comment: In English at least, that wording is confusing. The phrase "let $A$ such that $B$" suggests that the property $B$ defines object $A$. In other words, $B$ must be specified first. But you never specified what $Y_0$ is. It would make more sense (to me at least), if it said "$Y_0$ is the space such that $T(X)=Y_0$". or just use the standard term for such a set: image or range.

Comment: Ok, good to know that this is confusing. "$Y_0$ is the space such that $T(X)=Y_0$" it would be ok. Hm, or this is only one value for all the elements from $X$.

Comment: oh is $Y_0$ meant to be a single point, rather than a set? that would change the answer. Though it is unlikely. Showing that the constant function is measurable is rather trivial...

Comment: Yes, i know is obviously but i didn't do this type of exercise before and I need the formal proof.:/ The proof will be similiar to this one which you made?

Comment: If you want a formal proof that the constant function is measurable (and to be clear, I doubt that you are being asked that here), then please submit a new question and I will answer it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function between measurable spaces is measurable if the preimage of any measurable set is measurable.

A set $U$ is in $\mathcal{D}_{Y_0}$ if and only if there exists some $V\in\mathcal{D}_Y$ with $U=V\cap Y_0$ (this is the definition of the subspace sigma algebra $\mathcal{D}_{Y_0}$).  Then observe that $T^{-1}(V)=T_0^{-1}(V\cap Y_0).$ Therefore $T_0^{-1}(U)$ is in $\mathcal{A}$ if and only if $T^{-1}(V)$ is. $T$ is measurable if and only if $T_0$ is.